# how to use external objects in lightning app builder

Tags: lightning, lightning-connect

I've created an external object. Now I want to use it in Lightning App Builder. I dragged a filter list component onto the canvas. Then I was looking for this external object in the "Object" drop down. But I cannot see it there. In fact, I can only see case, contact, group and opportunity. Even other salesforce built-in objects aren't there.

I imported 2 of them from an external data source. My assumption is that regardless whether it's salesforce standard object, custom object or external object, after I created them, it should be transparent to lightning app builder. Maybe there is some place I need to explicitly configure to show this object in lightning app builder?

How can I get them to show up?

Comment: Do you mean a custom object or external object?

Comment: external object. I imported 2 of them from an external data source. My assumption though is that regardless whether it's salesforce standard object, custom object or external object, after I created them, it should be transparent to lightning app builder. Maybe there is some place I need to explicitly configure to say show this object in lightning app builder? I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add your custom object into Tab than you will be able to access it from Filtered List.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the External Object to 'Tabs' (Setup->Tabs) and it will be visible for you to be added as a Tab in your application.